# Index is in datetime64[ns] but still get TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, aggregate, aggregation

I'm trying to aggregate data for a daily and 15 min time interval. When I check the data type of the index it is in `datetime64[ns]`

Done this by:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
liquidation_1d_df = df.set_index('timestamp')
print(liquidation_1d_df.index.dtype)
```

However, I still get the error:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
```

I run the following code for aggregation:

```
liquidation_1d_df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='D'), 'exchange', 'side']).agg(total_liq = ('amount', 'sum'), avg_liq = ('amount', 'mean'))
```

Anyone an idea what is going wrong and how it can be solved?

Comment: Will you please provide provide a little sample of your dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of :

```
liquidation_1d_df = df.set_index('timestamp')
```

Try:

```
df.set_index('timestamp',inplace=True)
print(df.index.dtype)
```

Or if you don't want to change the original df

```
liquidation_1d_df = df
liquidation_1d_df.set_index('timestamp',inplace=True)
print(liquidation_1d_df.index.dtype)
```